Is it possible to get Instagram media likes using GraphQL API?
I'm trying to find a way to get Instagram media likes. There is an option to call media/{media_id}/likers/ API. However, it is rate limited and thus Instagram blocks these calls after some time. I know it is possible to get followers, for example, using query hash via GraphQL API. Is there the same way for media likes?
